# Is the Doctor still married?

Tags: doctor-who

In “The Snowmen” the Doctor kisses his new-found companion-to-be... but isn't he still married to River Song? Is he essentially cheating, was there another purpose to it, or is there something else I've missed?

I did wonder if it was something to do with the timelines getting mixed, but from memory it's her timeline that's going back while his goes forward, not the other way around.

Comment: I also couldn't help but wonder if the part of Madame Vastra wasn't originally meant to be River Song's. I mean, I was practically waiting for her to end a sentence with "... sweetie".

Comment: @Mr Lister I don't think so; Moffet has been on record as wanting to do more with Vastra and Jennie since they first appeared in "Good Man Goes to War".

Comment: I know, but in this ep, she was so... so familiar with the Doctor. "Nice to see you off your cloud and engaging again." "I'm not engaging again, I'm under attack!" "... You missed this, didn't you sweetie?"

Comment: It's not cheating if you're in different area codes.

Comment: I don't think the word "still" has any meaning when discussing time travellers. We need new tenses.

Comment: Since there was no one who officiated the ceremony, and the ceremony took place in a universe that ended up not existing, and the Doctor was in a robot at the time, does that mean he's actually married to River?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Doctor is still married and **technically** the soon-to-be companion is the one who did the kissing, not the Doctor, he just stood there, kind of surprised, looking all doctor-ish...

Answer (score 13):

River Song is

> dead

in the timeline.

There were a few minisodes that took place between the 6th and 7th season which showed the Doctor and River going on their final adventures. (Together the series was called [Night and the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Night_and_the_Doctor))

Yes, you might have seen River after that point, but all of Doctor Who is wibbley wobbley.

Comment: Wha?! What webisodes are you talking about? Links please I must see them!

Comment: @Deleteman I updated the link in my answer.

Comment: Well, ok, that explains a bit, I don't really interpret it as you put it on your spoiler, but I can't talk much here (on a comment) without spoiling it for others

Comment: @Deleteman haha idk if my spoiler is much of a spoiler. Should I remove the spoiler tag?

Comment: (you're right about the spoiler) Technically, on those episodes, we see 3 Rivers, one of them had to go and die (which would be the one we first saw on the library), but one last River stays with the current Doctor, so, I think it's safe to say that they're still married.

Answer (score 9):

Probably not. For one, he didn't initiate it. For two, he and River seem to have an open relationship, as the Doctor is also married to Queen Elizabeth I and Marilyn Monroe, and River once mentioned having dated a Nestene duplicate. For three, the legitimacy of their marriage is questionable since it took place in an aborted timeline that even River has said was irrelevant to the real world, when she tells Amy not to feel guilty about killing Madame Kovarian since it never happened due to the timeline's negation.

Answer (score 2):

The doctor is over a thousand years old, he also married queen elizabeth the first in the fiftieth so we have astablished he is some form of polygamist, did he marry anyone else? And just to make it clear the doctor is probably most in love with the tardis out of everyone, seriously

Answer (score 1):

in a sense they are married, the problem was stated by river that they were two time travelers going in opposite directions, their cases were the married river meets the doctor before he married her, and a married doctor meeting river who is yet to marry the doctor.

The sad thing is that they probably remember the one day that they were married and that their wedding day, and the days before they leave to do their own work, which means that their married selves ended meeting their unmarried younger selves. it's sad when you think about it.

The only other day, i would believe River and Doctor lived as man and wife, was when he finally took her to the singing towers, he knew that day was coming, and realized how much he loved her, that he gave her his sonic as a subtle message to 10 to save her in the end by uploading her into the CAL, and preserve the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

The Doctor is married to River, but the first time he ever met her is when she died. So to him, she's dead. Therefore, not cheating. He was, in some way, married to Queen Elizabeth, but she's dead too now. Same thing with Marilyn Monroe. He dated (kinda) Rose before he was married and kissed Amy when he still wasn't married. Kissing anyone else now still wouldn't count as cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought guys, but has anyone else realised that the Doctor and River aren't really married? In the weding the Doctor was suposed to tell her his name but he didnt. He told her to look in his eye! DOESN'T THIS MEAN THEY ARENT MARRIED?

Comment: Rachel, welcome to Stackexchange! This, as it stands, comes across as an opinion and not a good, objective answer. I feel you can clean it up and make it objective, and address the question fully. Oh, and have you seen the [faq], it's a good place to start with answering questions here! Catch you around! :D