# Did River Song really marry the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Wedding of River Song* we believe we are seeing the Doctor and River exchange vows, accompanied by parental consent and everything, **but**: the hand-fastening is done between River and *The Tesselecta*!! So did young Melody marry a *Time-Traveling Robot* from the future, the Doctor, who was after all inside the thing, or maybe even neither?

Related to: [Is the Doctor still married?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28947/is-the-doctor-still-married), but asking whether he has been married to begin with.

Comment: @calccrypto Yes, that could be, but he could merely have been a passenger, after all, he _was_ in the eyeball - with the TARDIS in the background, seconds after asking River to look into his eye. While he _could_ be controlling the Tesselecta, I was never certain he wasn't just along for the ride.

Comment: The Doctor was in control of the Tesselecta at the time... Besides, who is going to go after them? Theres no law saying that they are married. *They* say that they are married.

Comment: In the UK, the answer would be yes. A robot under full control would be considered a prosthetic device.

Comment: @BMWurm I forget what episode, but sometime before the wedding, the Doctor was given a "wish" by the Tesselecta's captain, and the Doctor used his wish to use the Tesselecta as a body double, which probably included him in control of it

Comment: @calccrypto That is done in _The Wedding of River Song_ via flashback.

Comment: @BMWurm I think you will have to define what constitutes marriage, since neither parental consent or presence (prosthetic mentioned by Richard) are requirements, depending on location. Then, by defining what constitutes marriage, you will have answered your own question.

Comment: @calccrypto But where would I start with that definition? Which law is to apply? Time Lord law, since River is a sort of Vortex-Human-Hybrid? Egyptian law, since it happens at Giza? Roman law, since Cleopatra and the Holy Roman Emperor Churchill have something going?? As is noted in an answer to the related question: It happens in an aborted timeline, that is - by River's own admission - of no consequence, although her mother counters that by remembering the events they _did_ in fact happen. Here in Germany it would not be binding, since personal physical **and** mental presence _is_ required.

Comment: @bmwurm - EU law states that you can use a prosthetic or the 'hand of another party' to complete a signature. That would make their wedding binding in Germany.

Comment: @BMWurm My point is, that it doesn't matter. River Song and the Doctor agree that they are happily married, and that is that. Is the happiness of two people not enough for you?

Comment: @calccrypto - Jerry Hall would disagree. http://www.theguardian.com/world/1999/jan/19/5

Comment: @Richard Seriously? lol. Well, in that case, there were laws in place. During the episode, time was in shambles, and laws were the least of anyone's worries.

Comment: @calccrypto The fictional happiness of two equally fictional people is nothing to me :) If you go by that, most questions here on SFF.SE are inherently pointless. ;)

Comment: @BMWurm In that case, I VTC because Doctor Who is not a legal drama, and any answer, no matter how good, will be most likely be pure speculation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ceremony itself may be of dubious legality or even historical accuracy as it can be observed to have never happened at all (as it took place in an aborted timeline), but the Doctor and River have both been shown to retain their memories of it, and they both consider it to be legitimately binding between themselves.

From "Asylum of the Daleks Prequel":

> MESSENGER: There is a woman who wants to meet you.
>
> DOCTOR: That's nice, but I'm married.

From "The Angels Take Manhattan":

> GRAYLE: What does that mean?
>
> RIVER: It means, Mister Grayle, just you wait till my husband gets home.

Comment: You can add quote from *The Time of The Doctor*: "They created a psychopath to kill you." "Totally married".. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to assume that the marriage was legally binding, or even that the "*battlefield marriage ceremony*" The Doctor performs actually exists.

- Captain Rory (native to that time period) has never heard of it.
- River Song (noted historian and archeologist) has never heard of it
- There seems to be no further attempt to notarise any sort of binding contract.

On top of that, the whole thing happens in a timeline that no longer exists and never happened.

If I had to guess, I'd say that the Doctor made the whole thing up so that he'd have an excuse to tell River a big secret without it seeming weird.

Comment: Who's going after the couple because they weren't legally married?

Comment: @calccrypto - Probably the same people who want 5 billion years of back council - tax from him

Comment: oh boy. maybe the Face of Boe can lend the Doctor some money

Comment: “without it seeming weird” — mission accomplished!

Comment: @calccrypto - He would, but you know how it is at the end of the month, hey, is that the time?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of rebooting the universe when Amy and River are chatting, Amy talks about murdering someone and River says it was in an aborted time line,  but Amy says she remembers it so it happened. This is like a hint that the Doctor and River remember their marriage (so its real) and was next mentioned as Amy being the mother-in-law.

Comment: Welcome! You should include some quotes and other evidence in order to support your answer!