# When did the Doctor and River Song marry?

Tags: doctor-who

There are questions about whether or not they actually did and [some suggest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66536/46407) that it didn't actually happen because it occurred in an abandoned timeline.

*However*, both River and the Doctor remember it happening... at some point. She still knows his name, (Season 7 - *"The Name of the Doctor"*), she still refers to herself as his wife, as does he.

One (crackpot) theory I had, was that they marry at the beginning of her Time-travelling timeline, and at the end of his.

*Do we know **when**, or even **if**, the Doctor and River Song got married?*

Comment: Wow... 1000 views on this in less than a day O.o

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The wedding occurred during the last episode of Season 6, [The Wedding of River Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wedding_of_River_Song). It was an impulsive action and the ceremony was very brief, so it is not entirely surprising that some people missed it or did not realize it's significance, or that both parties accepted it as genuine, despite its irregularity.

Comment: For completeness, the ceremony can be seen in this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMpw9Bibj0g

Comment: The OP seems well aware of this episode, since it's the one he refers to as "possibly not really happening" in the linked question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66527/did-river-song-really-marry-the-doctor/66536#66536

Comment: While that may be true, it is also true that this is the one and only time where the Doctor married River Song, at least so far.

Comment: But wait, there's still a plot hole!  She (*spoilers*) never actually learned his name, but she still knew it in "Silence in the Library"...

Comment: @Donald.McLean only time she married him *on screen*. The traveled quite a lot off-screen; her "last day" with him didn't come in any televised episode, but a DVD-extra short.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I believe this is the minisode you are referring to: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Night_(TV_story)

Comment: @Donald.McLean isn't that part of the abandoned timeline - following all the fuss about not killing the doctor stopped time, then she unloads the suit before she kills him; creating a completely alternate timeline?

Comment: @Ben I thought we were talking about Doctor Who. You know, the show where the rules are fast and loose and nothing is to be taken completely seriously.

Comment: @Donald.McLean *"Oh I'm sorry, what was that? Did some one mention... **The Rules??**" - The Time of the Doctor*. You have a point, sir. :P

Comment: C'mon.  Don'cha imagine they've popped off to Vegas a dozen times or so, just for the Elvis-impersonator drive-through weddings?  It would not surprise me if one of those times they were married by the REAL Elvis.